# FlutterFlow, add an element before every item in a list

Tags: flutter, dart, flutterflow

I have a list of strings equal to [25,26,27].
How can I turn that into [Category: 25, Category: 26, Category: 27]?

My code now is

```
String? newCustomFunction2(List<String>? input) {
  /// MODIFY CODE ONLY BELOW THIS LINE

  // join input strings and separate them by "," then return
  if (input == null || input.isEmpty) {
    return null;
  }
  String result = input.join("\n");
  return result;

  /// MODIFY CODE ONLY ABOVE THIS LINE
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
String? newCustomFunction2(List<String>? input) {
  if (input == null || input.isEmpty) {
    return null;
  }

 List<String> result = input.map((item) => 'Category: $item').toList();
  return result;
}
```